# How to query a table whose name is dependable on the id?

Tags: sql, database

I am making a website like Facebook. Whenever the user signup, a table named his/her 'id' is created in every database like messages, friends etc. My question is how to query that table.
This is what I tried so far:-

```
$id=$_SESSION['id'];
$id1=(string)$id;
$result=mysqli_query($conn2,"SELECT * from '$id1'");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
echo $row['frnd_id'];
}
```

But I am getting an error.

Comment: Seems like a terrible design to me. Database structure should be constant. creating a table for each user is a bad idea.

Comment: Then what is the alternative way for this @ZoharPeled

Comment: Give each user an ID and use foreign keys to bind with other tables.

Comment: You really don't want to incorporate dynamic querying like this on a website (or at all if it can be avoided).

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?